# What is the correct course of action to take when an earned badge isn't awarded?

Tags: support, badges

I have earned the Electorate badge on Stack Overflow (main site), and have received a message to say that it has been earned. I can also see the badge in the 'Select your next badge' => 'All' child-list, where it shows with a green tick next to it, denoting that it has indeed been earned. However, when I look on my profile page, and check the newest and next badges sections, the Elecorate badge does not show. *I would have thought that if the badge just hadn't been registered as having been awarded yet is should still appear in the publicly viewable next badge section, but it is no-longer there*.

Any ideas? What is the correct process for resolving this particular issue?

Comment: *"What is the correct course of action to take when an earned badge isn't awarded?"* Just wait.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Caching.  Always caching.

Be patient.

Comment: Spams 'Empty Cache and Hard Reload' with gay abandon ;o#).

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter It's server side caching.  There's nothing for you to do but wait.  That's why I said be patient.

Comment: Sweet! Just got it this second. Didn't even have to wait that long! **makes mildly ironic "This Is A Major Turning Point In My Life" face**